# Reference to one foreign key from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect one foreign key from multiple table's primary keys. Like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136Ki.png)

I've tried :

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT entity FOREIGN KEY (entity_id)
    REFERENCES MainTable(entitiy_id);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE MainTable 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES Table1(id),Table2(id),Table3(id);
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question does not contain a problem explanation. The first query looks good.

Comment: My problem is I can't connect multiple tables on one table.

Comment: Your first query looks good. What problems do you have with it?

Comment: You can't foreign key can reference 1 table only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not really clear what you want to achieve here.
The foreign key should go from a non-key column of the "child" table to the key column of the referenced table.

In your diagram, I would expect each one of Table, Table2 and Table3 to have a column "parent_id", and in every one of them you add a foreign key, which goes from the "parent_id" column to the key of the MainTable.

That said, the code is

ALTER TABLE `Table1`
    ADD COLUMN `parent_id` INT NULL;

ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_table1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES MainTable(uniqueId);